# How to SetState() of Parent when child is Updated in flutter

Tags: flutter, scroll, build, parent-child, setstate

I have a list view and inside the list view, there is a child widget which can grow when user tap on that.

I want to scroll to the bottom of the list when the user taps on the child and it grows.

when I pass callback function from the parent to the child to scroll to the bottom.
and call the function when the user tap on the child.

I get the following error: `setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.`

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

  void scrollToLast() {
    print("trying to scroll");
    setState(() {
      _controller.animateTo(
        _controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: Duration(microseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      controller: _controller,
      children: <Widget>[
        MyChildWidget(
          scrollToLast: this.scrollToLast,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback scrollToLast;
  MyChildWidget({
    this.scrollToLast,
  });
  @override
  _MyChildWidgetState createState() => _MyChildWidgetState(
        scrollToLast: this.scrollToLast,
      );
}

class _MyChildWidgetState extends State<MyChildWidget> {
  final VoidCallback scrollToLast;
  _MyChildWidgetState({
    this.scrollToLast,
  });
  int count = 5;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          this.count += 5;
        });
        this.scrollToLast();
      },
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: List<Widget>.generate(
          this.count,
          (int index) => Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: 30,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code. Thank you

Comment: my code is very large, its very hard to post, I will try.

Comment: Try to simplify it. It will allow us to understand the problem and help you. The error your are getting is because you are calling setState() while the build() function is being executed

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: consider using redux

Comment: You can pass the controller into your child and do all the work there. Then you will be able to call `setState` once with all of the work you desire. So instead of passing in the function simply pass in the controller and do `_controller.animateTo(
        _controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: Duration(microseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      );` in your child.

Comment: `.animateTo()` will not work without the set state, and I want to set the state of parent not child.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` 
code snippet

```
void scrollToLast() {
    print("trying to scroll");
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        _controller.animateTo(
          _controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: Duration(microseconds: 300),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        );
      });
    });
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

  void scrollToLast() {
    print("trying to scroll");
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        _controller.animateTo(
          _controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: Duration(microseconds: 300),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        );
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      controller: _controller,
      children: <Widget>[
        MyChildWidget(
          scrollToLast: this.scrollToLast,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback scrollToLast;
  MyChildWidget({
    this.scrollToLast,
  });
  @override
  _MyChildWidgetState createState() => _MyChildWidgetState(
      /*scrollToLast: this.scrollToLast,*/
      );
}

class _MyChildWidgetState extends State<MyChildWidget> {
  /* final VoidCallback scrollToLast;
  _MyChildWidgetState({
    this.scrollToLast,
  });*/
  int count = 5;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          this.count += 5;
        });
        widget.scrollToLast();
      },
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: List<Widget>.generate(
          this.count,
          (int index) => Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: 30,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Text('$index'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: "Demo",
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: MyWidget()),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```